# Como formatar arquivo Python no VS Code?

Tags: python, formatação, visual-studio-code

Estou tentando formatar um documento em Python no VS Code, e aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> command 'php.untrustValidationExecutable' not found

Como posso resolver isso?

OBS.: Outro problema, já instalei de tudo mas não formata nenhuma outra extensão além de HTML e JavaScript, quando pressiono <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

Comment: VSCode só vem com suporte para HTML, CSS, JavaScript e TypeScript, se você quiser que ele formate outras linguagens, você precisa baixar uma extensão. Você possui a extensão para Python?

Comment: Sim, eu possuo.

Comment: Quando você tenta formatar, a extensão não te sugere instalar autopep8, yapf ou black? Essas dependências são as responsáveis por formatar códigos em Python.

Comment: Sim, foram sugeridas. Eu instalei a autopep8, mas continua a mesma coisa.

Comment: Você pode começar por este [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial)

Comment: Certo, obrigado!

Answer (score -3):

autopep8 funcionou pra mim. atalho = shift + alt + f, apos a instalação da extensão

Comment: Isto não responde realmente à pergunta. Se você tiver uma pergunta diferente, pode fazê-la clicando em [Fazer pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Você também pode [adicionar uma gratificação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) para chamar mais atenção a esta pergunta quando tiver [pontos de reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficientes. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/444844)

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficiente, você vai poder deixar [comentários em qualquer publicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), mas, até lá, escreva apenas respostas que não [dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/444844)